# Variable importance for PCA transformed dataset having highly correlated (or same) variables (dependent and independent)

Tags: machine-learning, pca, importance

My setup:

```
1. X is my dataset of [m*n] shape. 

2. VARIABLES = list of n variables in X

3. X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X,100)
   # X_pca is PCA Transformed dataset with 100 PCs

4. FOR EACH VAR in VARIABLES:

       res = random_forest.fit(X_pca,VAR) 
       # apply random forest having X_pca as independent and VAR as dependent
```

I am aware that PCA is a way to deal with highly correlated variables (features), so there is no need to remove them.

Now my question is if we calculate variable_importance from this setup, will it be consistent, Given, VAR variable was part of X while calculating transformed dataset of 100 PCs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable importance measures for each principal component will be different since each of the 100 principal components is a linear combination of the original X variables, which successively maximize the explained variation in the space represented by the X variables. Geometrically, the first principal component is the linear combination that explains the most variation in the X space.

The overall model measures for things like fit (for example, R-square) will only be the same when you use all principal components in one model. So if you had 200 Xs you would need to use all 200 principal components to get the same overall model measures. The per-variable test statistics, variable importance metrics will still differ.

I hope this explanation helps you.